# CSS3 news ticker - trying to make infinite

Tags: css, news-ticker

I found a tutorial that shows how to make a CSS based news ticker, but it needs declarations to be entered for however many list items are included (there were 4 in the tutorial).

If I add another four list items, the ticker will still only got to the fourth, and then back up to the first (because of the keyframes in the CSS)

Is there a way the CSS animation can be applied to an infinite number of list items, as they get added?

HTML

```
<div id="news-ticker">
<span>Latest News</span>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Article one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Article two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Article three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Article four</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#news-ticker {
    overflow: hidden;
    height:1em;
    position: relative;
    padding:3px;
} 
span {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

ul {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
    -webkit-animation: ticker 10s cubic-bezier(1, 0, .5, 0) infinite;
    -moz-animation: ticker 10s cubic-bezier(1, 0, .5, 0) infinite;
    -ms-animation: ticker 10s cubic-bezier(1, 0, .5, 0) infinite;
    animation: ticker 10s cubic-bezier(1, 0, .5, 0) infinite;
}
ul:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -ms-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
li {line-height:1em;margin-bottom:.5em;}
#news_ticker a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ticker {
    0%   {margin-top: 0;}
    25%  {margin-top: -25px;}
    50%  {margin-top: -50px;}
    75%  {margin-top: -75px;}
    100% {margin-top: 0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes ticker {
    0%   {margin-top: 0;}
    25%  {margin-top: -25px;}
    50%  {margin-top: -50px;}
    75%  {margin-top: -75px;}
    100% {margin-top: 0;}
}
@-ms-keyframes ticker {
    0%   {margin-top: 0;}
    25%  {margin-top: -25px;}
    50%  {margin-top: -50px;}
    75%  {margin-top: -75px;}
    100% {margin-top: 0;}
}
@keyframes ticker {
    0%   {margin-top: 0;}
    25%  {margin-top: -25px;}
    50%  {margin-top: -50px;}
    75%  {margin-top: -75px;}
    100% {margin-top: 0;}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ab0axdsg/

Comment: No, there is not a way to do it without javascript

Comment: Okay, well javascript isn't definitely a No No, so would you be able to give me some idea how it would be done using JS?

Comment: You'd have to change the animation length and delay for each every time a news item is added